# DIV issue with collapsing and expanding

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to change around the code but for some reason it's not working as desired.
I want to put the DIV in the middle and while collapsing/expanding i want it slide down or up smoothly. If you click on Show/Hide the page shifts and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: `.collapsibleContainer { margin: 0 auto; }` will solve your centering, dunno exactly what your problem is otherwise. Your question is worded rather ambiguously--it's generally a good idea to say specifically which elements you're having problems with instead of "the DIV". There's a lot of div elements on your page.

Comment: It was working properly for me

Comment: If you don't want the page to shift, then wrap the image in a container that has its height.

Comment: your edit fixed the centering issue,. It's hard to explain but if you click on show/hide announcement, do you see the page shifts a little?

Comment: I'm guessing those who don't see it have very nice large and high res monitors so possibly it fits vertically without scroll even after it's expanded.  And really guys a down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shift is a result of the scrollbar showing or hiding based on the height of the webpage.  You can keep the scrollbar so no shift happens

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any shifting, but to center it, give it (the #sd rule) a width (other than 95% -- something closer to the image's width like 550px) and set the margin to `margin:0 auto`. Also get rid of the `align:center` rule.

```
#sd {
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page is shifting because when the announcement is expanded it is making the vertical scroll bar appear, hence shifting page content 18px (typically) to the left.  There are several ways to overcome this, the quick and dirty fix would be to set your page min-height to the height when Announcement is expanded, or you could achieve the same result by just setting `overflow-y:scroll` on the body  There are cleaner solutions, but now that you know the cause, I'm sure you will find a good solution for your particular requirements.

Comment: boy, you have to be quick around here.  There were no answers when I started typing and two by the time I was done.